# which of the following words is more appropriate to use - native vs. foreigner

Tags: synonyms

When I wonder if someone is outlander or native people (especially considering province or area), can I use these words below?

1. Native people/aborigine/indigenous/local
2. foreigner/outlander/the people from out of the town

Like

> "Are you local? Or are you native (people)?"
>   "Are you outlander? Or are you from out of the town?"

Answer (score 2):

The best question to ask would be: "Are you from here?"

However, similarly constructed questions like, "Are you from this area?" and "Do you live here?" would sound more 'natural'/conversational.

If you really prefer to use some of those you provided, you may use "foreigner/native".

I rarely hear people asking "Are you an aborigine?"